# Não envia form com a animação em Jquery do botão buscar

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho esse código que faz a animação do botão buscar em Jquery, o problema é que meu formulário não envia o dados digitados quando clica no botão submit com essa animação, como devo fazer?

HTML

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                <span class="fas fa-search procurar">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-collapse {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 30px !important;
        max-height: 270px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.input_procurar {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;

}

.procurar {
    font-size: 18px;
}
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
        padding: 8px 12px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border-width: 0px;
        color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
        background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
        border-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
        box-shadow: none;
        outline: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    padding: 16px 12px;
    font-size: 19px !important;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
    box-shadow: none;
}
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
        display: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .navbar-collapse {
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            padding-right: 38px !important;
        }
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
            width: 38px;
        }
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
            padding: 15px 12px;
        }
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
            font-size: 18pt;
            opacity: 0;
            display: none;            
            height: 50px;
        }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
    width: 40%;
}
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
            display: table-cell;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

JS

```
 $(function () {
        // Remove Search if user Resets Form or hits Escape!
        $('body, .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"]').on('click keyup', function(event) {
            console.log(event.currentTarget);
            if (event.which == 27 && $('.navbar-collapse .input_procurar form[role="search"]').hasClass('active') ||
                $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') == 'reset') {
                closeSearch();
            }
        });

        function closeSearch() {
            var $form = $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active')
            $form.find('input').val('');
            $form.removeClass('active');
        }

        // Show Search if form is not active // event.preventDefault() is important, this prevents the form from submitting
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]:not(.active) button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
                $input = $form.find('input');
            $form.addClass('active');
            $input.focus();

        });
        // ONLY FOR DEMO // Please use $('form').submit(function(event)) to track from submission
        // if your form is ajax remember to call `closeSearch()` to close the search container
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
                $input = $form.find('input');
            $('#showSearchTerm').text($input.val());
            closeSearch()
        });
    });
```

Bibliotecas

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

```
<!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: quais bibliotecas voce esta utilizando? alem do jquery

Comment: Creio que não envia nada porque o input não tem `name`.

Comment: coloquei o name no input mais ainda não faz o action no form

Comment: @JulioHenrique as bibliotecas acrescentei na pergunta

Comment: envia para quem? mesma pagina?

Comment: ele ão faz o action no form

Comment: então, manda pra quem?

Comment: como falei quando clico no botão submit do form, ele apenas volta a animação para a lupa, e não faz o action do form

Comment: Tire o segundo `event.preventDefault();`.. ele que impede do formulário ser submetido.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda @sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava na função de click, ela referencia um click em um botao dentro de um form com a classe active

```js
 $(function () {
        // Remove Search if user Resets Form or hits Escape!
        $('body, .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"]').on('click keyup', function(event) {
            console.log(event.currentTarget);
            if (event.which == 27 && $('.navbar-collapse .input_procurar form[role="search"]').hasClass('active') ||
                $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') == 'reset') {
                closeSearch();
            }
        });

        function closeSearch() {
            var $form = $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active')
            $form.find('input').val('');
            $form.removeClass('active');
        }

        // Show Search if form is not active // event.preventDefault() is important, this prevents the form from submitting
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]:not(.active) button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
                $input = $form.find('input');
            $form.addClass('active');
            $input.focus();

        });
        // ONLY FOR DEMO // Please use $('form').submit(function(event)) to track from submission
        // if your form is ajax remember to call `closeSearch()` to close the search container
        $(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
                $input = $form.find('input');
                alert('valor do input: '+ $form.find('input').val());
                console.log($input.val());
            $('#showSearchTerm').text($input.val());
            closeSearch()
        });
    });
```

```css
.navbar-collapse {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 30px !important;
        max-height: 270px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.input_procurar {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;

}

.procurar {
    font-size: 18px;
}
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
        padding: 8px 12px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border-width: 0px;
        color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
        background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
        border-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
        box-shadow: none;
        outline: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    padding: 16px 12px;
    font-size: 19px !important;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
    box-shadow: none;
}
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
        display: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .navbar-collapse {
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            padding-right: 38px !important;
        }
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
            width: 38px;
        }
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
            padding: 15px 12px;
        }
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
            font-size: 18pt;
            opacity: 0;
            display: none;            
            height: 50px;
        }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
    width: 40%;
}
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
            display: table-cell;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>


<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default active">
                                <span class="fas fa-search procurar">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                
  <div><p id='showSearchTerm'></p></div>
```

Coloquei assim:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
```

ou você pode mudar para

```
$(document).on('click', '#id-element', function(event) {
```

e dar um id pro botao

tipo:

```
<button type='button' id='id-element'> oi </button>
```